# Set on rails app cap, so that only one person could view our page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In joomla is such function, as turn web page on maintance, so that users see only page, that we are on reconstruction. Could such feature be done on ror web-application?
Also could i set some loging system, without generating any new devise model, just for example: enter password, to enter page on reconstruction?

I know that question is huge for so, but how it could be done on rails?

Just write something, so that all people, except one, who enter correct password, see only page "on reconstruction"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purpose you can set public/index.html page with "Under constuction text".
All another pages you can hide with http authentication.
Just simply add following code

## application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  if Rails.env.production?
    http_basic_authenticate_with name: "admin", password: "secret"
  end
end
```

Comment: help with public/index.html, i add it, but didn't see it... where i must see it?

Comment: Just put index.html.erb in yourapp/public/ directory. Also be sure that in your routes.rb file doesn't contain `root to: '...'`. And restart your server. When you visit your localhost:3000/ you can see your index.html page instead anyone page you set in routes before.

Comment: root to: '...'   - that was the problem